# Ajuda Select com prepare

Tags: php

Estou tentando fazer um select usando o prepare. Entretanto, ele simplesmente não consegue fazer esse select e me retorna que o usuário ou senha esta errado. Código abaixo:

```
<?php
session_start();

include("conexao.php");

$consulta = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM login WHERE login = ? AND senha = ?");
$consulta->bind_param("ss", $login, $senha);
$login = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['login']);
$senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['senha']);
$consulta->execute();
$row = $consulta->num_rows;

if($row == 1):
    $_SESSION['login'] = $login;
    header("Location: ../../boa/index.php");
    exit;
    else:
    $_SESSION['nao_logado'] = true;
    header("Location: ../index.php");
    exit;
    endif;
```

A forma que estou fazendo esta errada? Obrigado.

Comment: Você está utilizando as variáveis `$login` e `$senha` antes de inicializa-las.

Comment: Não procede sua informação, tendo em vista que eu estou usando o "PREPARE". No caso, estou executando, após as variáveis.

Comment: Em `bind_param` você está utilizando as variáveis `$login` e `$senha`, que nem foram inicializadas ainda. O que não procede?

Comment: Meu deus! Meu amigo, se você não tem conhecimento sobre o PREPARE, por favor, não comente. Estude um pouco https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Qual a necessidade do `mysqli_real_escape_string` se você já está utilizando um _prepared statement_?

Comment: Tentei usar sem ele, porém, mesmo assim da senha incorreta

Comment: No var_dump ele sempre mostra o "  public 'num_rows' => int 0"

Comment: Tenta pegar o resultado com get_result() para ver pq isso ta acontecendo

Comment: já resolvi amigo, grato.

Answer (score -1):

O problema era que eu não estava mostrado ao php o resultado se foi positivo ou negativo. Código correto abaixo:

```
<?php
session_start();

include("conexao.php");

$consulta = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM login WHERE login =? AND senha =?");
$consulta->bind_param("ss", $login, $senha);
$login = $_POST['login'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];
$consulta->execute();
$consulta->store_result();
$row = $consulta->num_rows;


if($row == 1):
    $_SESSION['login'] = $login;
    header("Location: ../../boa/index.php");
    exit;
    else:
    $_SESSION['nao_logado'] = true;
    header("Location: ../index.php");
    exit;
    endif;
```